# PHP variable as javascript popup

Tags: php, javascript, popup, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating javscript function to destroy php session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060735/creating-javscript-function-to-destroy-php-session)

Hi I am trying to create a php variable that will display itself as a popup.  Here is the code I have...

```
    <?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start(); 
 $var = "";

 // echo variable from the session, we set this on our other page 
 if ($_SESSION['color'] == "") {
        $var = "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php');' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
    } else {
    echo "Hello, ";
    }
 echo $var;
 ?>
```

I can't seem to arrange the semicolons and quotes correctly.  Can someone please show me how this is done.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the quote character you are using to delimit your string within the string with the escape character (`\`)...

```
$var = "<a href=\"JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php');\" class=\"two\">Sign In</a>";
```

Alternatively, you can mix quotes, i.e. use single quotes to delimit your string and double quotes for quotes around your attributes or vice versa.

You could also use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Answer (score 1):

In `"<a href='JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php');' class='two'>Sign In</a>";` the 2nd `'` closes the `href` tag. You need to escape it, so you would do something like:

```
$var = "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php\");' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
```

So that when it actually outputs you get `<a href='JavaScript:newPopup("http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php");' class='two'>Sign In</a>`