# Creating javascript function to destroy php session

Tags: php, javascript, session, destroy

I am having trouble figuring out how to create a javascript function that will destroy a php session.  I have a clickable link that will call a function called destroyphpsess.  I think this is all right so far.  Now I need to define the javascript function.  This is the code I have so far...

```
if ($_SESSION['color'] == "") {
    $var = "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/register.php\");' class='two'>Register</a> | <a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php\");' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
} else {
    $var = "Hello, ".$_SESSION['color'] ."! | " . "<a href=\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/index.php\" onclick=\"destroyphpsess()\" class='two'>Log Out</a>";
}
echo $var;
```

Now I need to define the javascript function.  This is where I am having trouble.  This is the basic outline I have so far...

```
function destroyphpsess()
{
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
}
```

If someone could help me with the function I would appreciate it!
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you use ajax and call a page which will destroy the session

Comment: +1 for coming back with a much better question! :D

Answer (score 11):

Your JavaScript runs client-side, and your PHP runs server-side.  You can't call PHP functions from JavaScript this way.  You have two options:

1. Do an AJAX call to a server-side script that clears the session data *(recommended, for consistency and proper clearing of that stuff server-side)*
2. Clear the PHPSESSID cookie with JavaScript *(won't work if you reconfigure how you handle sessions, or if sessions are handled by URL parameters)*

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant JavaScript runs client-side and PHP runs server-side.

Answer (score 6):

A PHP session generally uses a cookie that is stored client side. The following code will clear that cookie thus unlinking the session.

`document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';`

Comment: +1 I'd use `session_destroy` from an AJAX call... I would never thought of doing this through cleaning a cookie, but I liked the idea.

Comment: That was my other thought, but yeah i was thinking all client side. This code will leave the session hanging on the server side until it expires

Comment: where would i put this line of code?  would i put it in the function?

Comment: You would put this code at the point of which you want to end the session. This is javascript. So maybe put it in a logout event handler of something of that sort

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on a link and for the session to instantly be destroyed while staying on the same page.  So where would the above code go in reference to what I already have?

Comment: if its a link then `<a href="#" onclick="document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;'; return false;">Destroy!!</a>`

Comment: Great thank you.  What is the purpose of the date part?  Will this instantly destroy the session?

Comment: Yes when the expire data of a session is prior to the current date, the session will be removed by the browser.

Comment: $var = "Hello, ".$_SESSION['color'] ."! | " . "<a href=\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/index.php\" onclick='document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;'; return false;'>Log Out</a>";

Comment: but it is not destroying the session, bc it is still displaying the name?  any ideas?

Comment: Oh if you want to go to a different page, remove the `return false` at the end of the page. This return false is making it so the hyperlink doesnt execute. I assumed you were using this a just a button sorry

Comment: All good. :)  I want it so that after the user clicks the link the page destroys the session, and refreshes the current page.  I got rid of the return false and it does the same thing it displays the session info.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the link to where I am testing this.  yourfantasyfootballreality.com       If you select Articles then select Home, you will notice that it says Hello Red! | Log Out   in the top left corner.  When you select Log Out you still see Hello Red!  when it shoud display Register | Log In

Answer (score 0):

Everyone keeps saying AJAX. This would be a good idea if you want to clean up the cookie on the server side as well, but I think if you knew what AJAX was you probably would have used it already...

I found [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) pretty confusing when I first came across it. So what I would suggest is having a look at and maybe using jQuery's [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) functionality. Including jQuery for just one function is probably overkill, but it might be a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript runs client-side, and your PHP runs server-side. You can't call PHP functions from JavaScript this way. You have two options:

Do an AJAX call to a server-side script that clears the session data (recommended, for consistency and proper clearing of that stuff server-side)
Clear the PHPSESSID cookie with JavaScript (won't work if you reconfigure how you handle sessions, or if sessions are handled by URL parameters)